# Making both results of an if statement be equal to one variable in php

Tags: php

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$sum = 0;
if ($number >= 23)
{
    do { 
    $sum += $number % 10;
    } while ($number = (int) $number / 10);
    $sum = $number_edited;
    echo "$number_edited";
}
else
{
    $number = $number_edited;
    echo "$number_edited";
}
```

All the loop is for is to calculate the sum of all digits in $number, it's working and can be ignored.

This is not working, there is no result, instead I am getting a notice: `undefined variable number_edited`.

The reason why I am trying to only have one variable at the end is because I would like to do another bunch of calculations with `$number_edited`.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: In the code you didn't have defined $number_edited anywhere

Comment: did you mean to use `$sum` ?

Comment: @Jenz That's what I'm struggling with, I want to define it as either $sum or $number, depending on the criteria of the if statement. I tried `$sum = $number_edited;` and `$number = $number_edited;` in what way do I need to rewrite that to define it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some error in your code

```
 $number_edited=0; // declare
 $sum = 0;
 if ($number >= 23)
   {
     do { 
         $sum += $number % 10;
        } while ($number = (int) $number / 10);
    $number_edited=sum;//your declaration is wrong. This will make $number_edited equal to $sum.
    echo "$number_edited";
   }
else
  {
   $number_edited=$number;//also here
   echo "$number_edited";
  }
```

Remember that left side value is always assigned by the value on the right. Not assign value from left to right. In other word, value on the left side is "new", right side is "old".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are neither declaring the variables $number or $number_edited before you start the 'if statement'.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the variable `$number_edited` in wrong way. While declaring a variable the left hand side should contain the name of the variable and the right hand side should contain the value of the variable,

For eg: `$var=1;`

`$var` should be the name of the variable (in the left hand side) and 1 should be the value of the variable (in the right hand side).

So try with this.

```
$sum = 0;
if ($number >= 23)
{
    do { 
    $sum += $number % 10;
    } while ($number = (int) $number / 10);
    $number_edited=$sum;
    echo "$number_edited";
}
else
{
    $number_edited=$number;
    echo "$number_edited";
}
```